# find last row start_date & previous row end_date from database table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table name Interest rate with fields Start Date & End Date.their are two records in my database table interest rate such as

**Sr.No.      start_date       end_date**

**1           2014-04-26       2014-05-03**

**2           2014-04-27       2014-05-04**

**3           2014-04-02       2014-05-31**

In the above table the last row start date is less than previous two rows end date then how to check in the database that the end date is greater than start date.what is the SQl query write to find that all previous end date is greater than last row start date.

For e.g: In the above table last row start date is 2014-04-02 & all rows end date is 2014-05-03, 2014-05-04 , 2014-05-31 which is greater than 2014-04-02 then show all records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using sql query like this

```
SELECT end_date FROM your_table 
WHERE end_date > (SELECT start_date FROM your_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you write the expected result on the above data set. The end date in each row is greater than the start date.